# Concat not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have 2 files

- 1st Containing Data (No Column Header)
- 2nd Containing Column Header

I want to combine this 2 into 1 file. My approach push the data into dataframe and used concat on them get the file result set.

My Code Till now

```
import pandas as pd
from xlrd import open_workbook

#contains mapping, Column present
#DataFileName   FolderLocation  ColumnFileName
#Data1           F:\Desktop      ColFile1
#Data2           F:\Desktop      ColFile2

filelocation = 'F:\Desktop\Mapping.xlsx'
wb = open_workbook(filelocation)
Separator = ','
items = []
for sheet in wb.sheets():
    number_of_rows = sheet.nrows
    number_of_columns = sheet.ncols
    for row in range(1, number_of_rows):
        for col in range(number_of_columns):
            ColumnFileName = sheet.cell(row,0).value
            Path = sheet.cell(row,1).value
            DataFileName = sheet.cell(row,2).value

            DataFileCompName = Path + "\\" + DataFileName +FileExtension
            ColumnFileCompName = Path + "\\" + ColumnFileName+ FileExtension
            HeaderDataFrame = pd.read_csv(ColumnFileCompName,sep=Separator)#,index_col=0)#,header=0)
            DataDataFrame = pd.read_csv(DataFileCompName,sep=Separator)#,header=None)

            CompleteDataFrame = pd.concat([HeaderDataFrame,DataDataFrame], ignore_index=True,axis=1)
```

Now, With concat i want the result set as

```
HeaderDataFrame
DataDataFrame
```

Whereas i am getting result as

```
HeaderDataFrame|DataDataFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the axis from axis=1 to axis=0 in your code, so

```
CompleteDataFrame = pd.concat([HeaderDataFrame,DataDataFrame], ignore_index=True,axis=0)
```

Comment: With axis=0 the ouput i am getting is a straight line.

Comment: @SachinKamble - please elaborate what you mean? what straight line.The clearer your description is the better someone can help

Comment: straight line as in , i am getting records in 1 line i.e. single row

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you want to combine them, but usually you would just use the header data (which is one row I presume) as columns labels in your data, and for that you don't need `concat`.

You can add headers to your dataframe by renaming the columns like this:

```
df.columns = [label1, label2, label3, ...]
```

You just need your header as a list of column labels in the same order as the dataframe, and of course it must have the same number of labels as your number of columns.

Alternatively you can use the `names`-parameter of the appropriate file reading function to directly assign column labels to the files you're reading, e.g. using `read_csv()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=[label1, label2, label3, ...])
```